# C#/.NET: Is `typeof(variable)` a possible language feature?

Tags: c#, .net, specifications

On a few separate occasions, I have tried to coax the declared type out of a variable, relatively far from its declaration, only to find out that `typeof(T)` only works on type names.

I was wondering if there would be any breaking changes to allow `typeof(variable)` as well.

For example, with this code:

```
class Animal { /* ... */ }
class Goat : Animal { /* ... */ }

/* ... */

var g = new Goat();
Animal a = g;

Console.WriteLine(typeof(Goat));
Console.WriteLine(typeof(Animal));
Console.WriteLine(g.GetType());
Console.WriteLine(a.GetType());
```

You get something like:

> Goat
>   Animal
>   Goat
>   Goat

Why is it not possible to do this:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(g));
Console.WriteLine(typeof(a));
```

> Goat
>   Animal

I have given the spec a cursory glance, and can't find any conflict.  I think that it would clear up the question 'Why this type?' when using the `typeof` operator.

I know that the compiler is capable, here.  An implementation using extension methods is actually trivial:

```
public static Type TypeOf<T>(this T variable)
{
    return typeof(T);
}
```

But that feels dirty, abusing the type-inference of the compiler.

Comment: How do you want to use this? And why can't it be done using `is`?

Comment: First, do you have something against GetType()? Second, your example behavior of typeof(g) and typeof(a) is incorrect. The underlying type of a is, in fact, Goat (not Animal).

Comment: @0xA3: I find myself using `typeof` for reflection and interop.  `is` doesn't give you access to all of that.

Comment: `"string".TypeOf<object>` returns `typeof(object)`, while `object x = "string"; return x.GetType();` returns `typeof(string)`.

Comment: @Justin:  I would expect it to act exactly like the extension method I delcared, such that it would use the declared type of the variable, rather than the most specific type.

Comment: "breaking change" generally doesn't refer to conflicts in the spec, it refers to conflicts with existing code. Is that what you meant? In that sense, your suggestion would be a massive breaking change (consider a property and a type with the same name, for example).

Comment: @dtb: Well, I was implying that you would let the type-inference run, rather than specifying a type parameter.  The goal here is to avoid having to write-out types.

Comment: @John - Why would you want the declared type over the underlying type?

Comment: I'd guess that typeof() is turned into an actual Type instance at compile time, and so cannot be used with instances.  The reason why `typeof(T);` works is that generics in .NET *aren't c++ templates*; all types are determined at compile time.

Comment: @Justin: Using that argument, why would you ever use `typeof()` over 'object.GetType()`?

Comment: @Will:  Is there any reason that the *declared* type of a variable wouldn't be known at compile-time?

Comment: @John - That wasn't an argument. It was an honest question. I'm wondering what situation you would want that functionality in (I'm curious as to when you'd want that kind of behavior).

Comment: @Justin:  Well, often when loading plug-ins, I want to know whether a variable I have can be assigned based on an object coming from another assembly.  I usually call `typeof(Blah.Blah.IPlugin).IsAssignableFrom(a)`, but I think that `typeof(a).IsAssignableFrom(b)` is more clear, since it answers the 'Why' of the type-cast to follow.

Comment: @John At this point, I fall back to the easy answer:  "Because that's not the way it was designed."

Comment: @John `public static bool IsPlugin(this object me){ return typeof(IPlugin).IsAssignableFrom(me.GetType()); }` (with null check of course)

Comment: @Will: Yeah, that is more-or-less what I'm doing now.  However, that still feels like a work-around.  Also, there is an additional scenario where clarity would be enhanced:  Using `Marshal.SizeOf()`.

Comment: @John, if you want to know whether a variable can be assigned from an object, why not just use `as` or `is`?  `IPlugin a = b as IPlugin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose it's allowed:

```
class Animal { }

string Animal;
Type t = typeof(Animal); // uh-oh!
```

Comment: This is not necessarily a problem...  Under your scenario, typeof() could behave like any other reference to the Animal symbol: the local variable wins.

Comment: That happens all over, I don't see a reason that this should be an issue.  Take this for example:  `var System = string.Empty;  var b = System.Double.NaN;`

Comment: To be fair, allowing such ambiguous variable names in the first place is asking for trouble already.  And he could rephrase the question to get around it, e.g. "why don't they have a `GetDeclaredType()` method to get the declared type, rather than the runtime type."

Comment: @gmagana, if the local variable wins, then you just broke lots of pre-existing code.  If the type wins, then this syntax is incredibly dangerous, since it's very unlikely you know every single type that is currently in scope.

Comment: @tnyfst, yeah, code breaks, but now it's too late (there is already a ton of code making assumptions out there).  Not that I feel any pity for code that names multiple in-scope symbols the exact same name...  Interesting question, nonetheless

Comment: @gmagana: So you do not like `public Color Color { get; set; }`?

Comment: @gmagana, don't think variable, think property name.  It's very common for an Employee property to return an Employee instance.  In fact, I think the Framework Design Guidelines suggested that. (I see Jason beat me to it with the same example).

Comment: @John Gietzen: Your example causes a compile-time error. Was that your point?

Comment: @Jason. Yes, that was the point.  Why wouldn't it be possible to raise a compile time error in the case you specified?  As I see it, if this is an issue, you could just raise an error (or, maybe warning) in the case that there is a conflict.  Again, keep in mind that I said `typeof(variable)`, not `typeof(expression)`.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem here is that .GetType() is older than typeof().  There used to be a day in C# where you needed to do

```
"0".GetType()
```

in order to get the String type (for example), until typeof() was born.  I think if the concept had been part of the original language design, then indeed it might work as you describe.  Due to typeof() being a late introduction to the language, then the designers had to make a choice: Obsolete/deprecate/remove .GetType() (and in the process make many, many uses of it obsolete), make typeof() overlap in functionality with GetType() (which is what you are asking), or make typeof()'s usage not overlap with GetType().  I think the C# people simply chose not to make the functionality overlap (to keep things simple and clear), and so typeof() was restricted in the way it is today.

Comment: Fair enough, but I'd like to hear from a language designer about that decision process.

Comment: @gmagana: Your answer seems to assume that `GetType` and `typeof` do identical things. This is not the case.

Comment: @0xA3: Well, the question does too, then.  All I'm saying is that, from a certain POV, the decision to not overlap in functionality makes sense, as @John points out, it would be interesting to see what the actual decision process was when typeof() was put into the language...

Comment: @0xA3: I think that he is saying that the language designers decided to not have the two methods overlap, and are therefore not identical.

Comment: gmagana: I don't know if you're making that up or just not remembering, but `typeof` has *always* been part of C#. I have a prerelease spec from 1999 that has it. It's missing the `is` operator, but that was added before C# 1.0 was released.

Comment: What functionality overlap? GetType() gets the type of an object instance. typeof() gets the actual System.Type of a type. They're completely different, which is why this entire question makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: @Gabe, you are correct, my memory is selective.  The very first draft of the ECMA standard has the typeof() keyword included. I was positive it was not, but you are correct. See http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-WITHDRAWN/ECMA-334,%201st%20edition,%20December%202001.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply trying to get the type of something, you can just call

```
Type t1 = myObject.GetType();
```

it should give to the behavior you want.

Comment: That doesn't get the declared type, but rather gets the most specific type of the object referenced. The declared type is, in essence, invisible to the run-time, but is useful in reflection.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking two different questions here, the first being why is there no operator for finding the declared variable type, and the other asking why can't *typeof(o)* be the equivalent of *o.GetType()*.

For the first, the reason is because it serves no purpose, the declared type of a variable is by definition always known at compile time.  Adding an operator for it would add no value.

For the other, the problem is that using typeof(instance) causes problems with resolution.  As Jason mentioned above, consider:

```
public class Animal {}
string Animal;
Type t = typeof(Animal);
```

What is t?  If you treat *t* as *typeof(string)*, then you just adding massive breaking changes to the language.  Imagine all the code out there that currently assumes *t* is an Animal, which is currently correct.

If you treat *t* as *typeof(Animal)*, though, then your code is incredibly brittle.  Imagine the situation where there was no Animal class when you wrote the code, but a year later somebody added an Animal class in some namespace that you imported.  Your code would break because the resolution rules would now use the Animal type rather than the local variable.

Comment: No, I do not want `typeof(o)` to be equivalent to 'o.GetType()`.  That is not **at all** what I want.  I want `typeof(o)` to be a way of finding the declared type of `o`, equivalent to how `typeof(T)` works on the typename.  I realize that there are name conflicts, as Jason said, but then why allow name conflicts at all in the language?

Comment: Again, your argument against it would seem to support banning the use of namespace-conflicting variable names. That is why the `global::` keyword exists.

Comment: @John, I mentioned the "Get declared type" issue in the first part of my answer; it serves no purpose since the declared type is known at compile time.  For the second, I don't know if you just don't see the breaking change or you feel that breaking changes are unimportant.  Your question was whether this would be a  breaking change; the answer is yes.

Comment: I see the breaking change, now.  I think that this would break very few cases, and therefore do think that the breaking change would be acceptable...

Comment: Saying that the type is known at compile time, and therefore "it serves no purpose" is a little bit strange.  Are you saying that you can think of no use case for accessing the declared type of a variable, rather than the specific type?

Comment: @John, yes, I can think of no instance where you would need to determine the declared type of a variable at runtime, nor an instance where doing so wouldn't simply add brittleness and confusion.   Why do you want this?  As for the number of breaking changes, it's incredibly common to name a property after the type it returns; I don't know why you think that's rare.

Comment: @tnyfst:  Who said anything about properties?  Let me reiterate:  `typeof(variable)` **NOT** `typeof(expression)`.

Comment: @John, you keep going back and forth on this.  Is `typeof(AmbiguousPropertyAndTypeName)` a compile error in your proposed syntax, or does it silently resolve to the typename? The first is a  massive breaking change, the second is very brittle.